# How can I distable coub.com weekly notifications

Tags: safari, mojave

Every week I receive a Mac notification about Coub.com weekly. If I click into it it will take me [here](https://coub.com/weekly/2019/47) on Safari browser.
I was trying to disable it by changing the preferences -> notifications -> Safari. But it didn't help. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the notification is really coming from the coub.com website, you would disable that in Safari preferences, not System Preferences.

Go to the Safari Preferences > Websites tab, select Notifications on the left, and you'll see a list of all the websites that have asked you for permission to send notifications. From there, you can change the notification preference for coub.com to "Deny".